# How to get object name and object count using Django

Tags: python, django

I want this kind of thing to display in HTML page

Location name                    Count

London                          10

Manila                        8

Location Name is in the database. I want to display the location name and how many times that location name was repeated.

view.py...

```
class MapListView(ListView):
    model = Map

      def get_queryset(self):


       return Map.objects.annotate(LocName_count=Count('LocName')).order_by('-LocName_count')[:9]
```

map_list.HTML...

```
{% for object in object_list %}
<tr>

    <td>{{object}}</a></td>
    <td><a href="{{object.get_absolute_url}}">{{ object.LocName }}</a></td>
    <td><a href="{{object.get_absolute_url}}">{{ object.LocName_count }}</a></td>


</tr>


{% endfor %}
```

models.py...

```
class Map(models.Model):

    # Fields
    LocName = models.TextField(max_length=255)


    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-pk',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.pk

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('Home_map_detail', args=(self.pk,))


    def get_update_url(self):
        return reverse('Home_map_update', args=(self.pk,))
```

I used like above but it not working
Please help

Comment: What's the error message or nothing happens?

Comment: Values are came but they are not separate(location Name+Count)
I need location Name and count separately because .Location name link with the google map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *.values()* and then *.annotate()* of django ORM for GROUP BY query

```
Map.objects.values('LocName').annotate(count=Count('LocName'))
```

the output will be

```
[
 {'LocName': 'London', 'count': 10}, 
 {'LocName': 'Manila', 'count': 8}
]
```

You can now easily loop over it in your template.

Comment: Thanks I used like below. My issue fixed.Thanks a lot
return Map.objects.values('LocName').annotate(count=Count('LocName')).order_by('-count')

Comment: could you please tell me how I get details view link for LocName. Because now when I click current link it redirect same page

Comment: Above query will output a grouped result means if there are 2 Map object having LocName `london` than query will merged both object and result a combined dict as above. it is not a object of Map class. so you can not get any detail url from `get_absolute_url` this is not callable.

Comment: I did what you said but I get full list of location name with duplicates Also it count every record as one.
Am I doing Wrong?

Comment: @Buddika as it is a grouped query you can not get a particular object id, please read my above comment, you have to figure out other way around.

Comment: If you want to show Detailview you have to list all object separately either they are duplicate LocName.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `count()` to get a count of the data, but can u show your whole model code to be sure

Comment: thanks for response.I updated question  with model.py
Thanks

Comment: could you please tell me how to show the location name and location count in details.HTML

Comment: I will need to see your models.py to know what am working with

Comment: I added models.py 
could you please check

Comment: It would be best to create another class with the name Location so as to be able to call the count() function easily, it would have a foreign key to the Map class

Comment: Because a detailView by default only shows detail about on field

Comment: Thank you I will try like that

Comment: i don't think its good to create another class to keep same information.